# IMCE ckeditor cant upload image

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, users, files

So I moved my website from local to the server, and now I cant upload any pictures on the server anymore. after clicking on the "browse server" and hitting on "upload" and the ajax loading circle works a bit and back to step one. nothing happens!

also I can upload files via ftp or filefield but not via imce, thought it might be imce, updated to the latest version. still no changes.

There's no error in my dblog and client error console neither.

Comment: Is there any message in your error log?

Comment: nothing, also in my browser js error logs, all clean

Comment: also I can upload files via ftp or filefield but not via imce, thought it might be imce, updated to the latest version. still no changes

Comment: Please add the information that other ways to upload works directly to your question. I was about to vote to close your question as a duplicate, and then I saw your comment that changed it for me :)